# Video.js last frame image

Tags: javascript, html, image, video.js

I'm having difficulties with the Video.js poster image on the last frame displaying.

The poster image displays at the beginning of the video, no problem. However, when I use the code below, nothing displays and I get a

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: myId is not defined index.html:247 (anonymous function)
```

The code I'm using is as follows:

Video:

```
<video class="video-js vjs-default-skin" muted preload="auto" width="1903" height="auto" autoplay="true" data-setup="{}" poster="assets/images/wows.png">
<source src="assets/movies/TheWolfofWallStreet.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
<source src="assets/movies/TheWolfofWallStreet.webm" type='video/webm' />
<track kind="captions" src="demo.captions.vtt" srclang="en" label="English"></track><!-- Tracks need an ending tag thanks to IE9 -->
<track kind="subtitles" src="demo.captions.vtt" srclang="en" label="English"></track><!-- Tracks need an ending tag thanks to IE9 -->
<p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
```

The script I have, from a previous question asking the same thing:

```
  <script>var myPlayer = videojs(myId);
myPlayer.on('ended', function(){
  this.posterImage.show();
});</script>
```

The script tag is right at the end of the HTML doc but, being a little behind on my JS knowledge, I can't figure out what I need to define (myId) to.

Everything else is working exactly as it should, the whole idea behind this is to use the last frame in the video as a platform for users to click to navigate to separate sections of the site currently being built, any ideas on what I've, clearly, done wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`myId` would be the `id` attribute of the player, but you don't have one.

```
<video id="myPlayer" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" …
<script>var myPlayer = videojs("myPlayer"); …
```

Comment: That appeared to give me the following issue in the video.js file:


`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'myPlayer' of undefinedvideo.js:39 vjsindex.html:267 (anonymous function)`


Pertaining to this line:


`// If a player instance has already been created for this ID return it.
    if (vjs.players[id]) {
      return vjs.players[id]; `

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what's different. To my eyes, nothing. I even copied across your code to make sure. It's still not displaying. I'm using a local version but that should affect this. I'm pulling across the CDN info and there's no errors in the code.

I managed to get this working by hiding the video and replacing it with the poster but it's not ideal & feels kinda messy..